# Why my ubuntu 22.04 only charge my phone when it connect with usb?

Tags: usb

When i connect my android phone with usb to my ubuntu 22.04 laptop it charge my phone only not showing option of transfer file in my phone.

Comment: It could be a cable issue. Were you able to transfer files before ? Have you tried out using a different cable ?

Comment: Edit your question to show us the complete output of `lsusb` with the phone connected and without the phone connected. If the output is identical (phone not detected), then it's a cable or Ubuntu issue. If the phone is detected, then it's an Android issue.

Answer (score 0):

On my phone running Android 11, once connected to my laptop, I have to manually select the option to activate file transfers. This is on the phone, not the laptop.

Comment: I didn't get any popup message to my phone it charge only when i connect with my ubuntu laptop, but in window it show that option to share file

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well, but I tried a different USB port with the same cable and after about 1 minute the phone showed up in the file browser.

I have had this experience before, with other Android phones and other laptops. I don't know if there is meant to be a difference between USB ports on the same computer, but it's happened several times now, so it's worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

Biggest other gotcha that can happen on this and did to me:

Your phone CABLE does not have the internal wires (4 wires) connected and only has 2. So, it will charge but it won't show up on your computer as a usb device.
Good explanation here from Sony:

In general, a fully equipped USB cable consists of 4 copper wires:

```
Two wires are used for charging purposes
Two wires are used for data transferring.
```

Although all USB cables have the same external appearance, some cables are “charge-only”, and the two data transfer copper wires (named D+ and D- data lines) will not be included in the cable or will be disconnected. We recommend using USB-cables that have all four wires connected, as the absence of these data transfer wires can potentially cause errors.
How do I know my USB cable has four wires?

Finding out can be a challenge, as there are inconsistencies between USB cables across manufacturers. If you are using a Sony product without a supplied USB cable, please ask your local retailer specifically for a data-transfer capable USB-cable. You can also check yourself, as it should be listed on the packaging.

The first item to check is the USB-cable supplied with your smartphone. It should be data-transfer compatible.